# Difference between being and be

Tags: difference, negation

For example:

> 1. don't be aggressive
> 2. don't being aggressive

Could you tell me which one is used in which situation?

Answer (score 1):

The verb which follows "do" or "don't" is always in the basic form, never the "-ing" form.

"Don't be..." is correct.  "Don't being...." is not correct English.